# How to fix "@types/node/index.d.ts is not a module"?

Tags: node.js, typescript, webpack, webpack-2, typescript-typings

I have installed node type definitions using the following command

```
npm install --save-dev @types/node
```

After that, when I try to import the node type definitions using the following statement

```
import { Process } from '@types/node';
```

or

```
import { Process } from 'node';
```

I get the following error

```
[ts] File '<root_path>/node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts' is not a module.
```

I am sure there is something very basic that I am missing here but I cannot figure out.

Few more things

1. I am using Windows 8
2. I am using Visual Studio Code

Here is how my `tsconfig.json` looks

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": "lib",
    "typeRoots": [
        "node_modules/@typings"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

And here is how my `webpackconfig.js` looks

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {  
  entry: './ts/handler.ts',
  target: 'node',
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.ts(x?)$/, loader: 'ts-loader' },      
      { test: /\.json$/, loader: 'json-loader' }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.tsx', '.jsx']
  },
  output: {
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs',
    path: path.join(__dirname, '.webpack'),
    filename: 'handler.js'
  },
};
```

Comment: You don't need to import from `@types/node`. You need to import just from 'node'. Also you need to change `typeRoots` to `[ "node_modules/@types" ]` in your `tsconfig.json`

Comment: @embarq getting same error after importing just from `node`

Comment: @embarq still the same error after changing `typeRoots`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Instead of using:

```
import { Process } from '@types/node';
```

You need to change your `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"]
  }
}
```

After doing that the process variable becomes available as a global.

Sometimes you will need to import from a Node.js module like for example the `fs` module. You can do:

```
import * as fs from "fs";
```

You don't need to import `fs` from "node" or from "@types/node".

You can learn more [here](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/quick/nodejs.html).

Comment: I have made the change and I am about to test it now. Just a quickie - so I cannot use the `Process` interface defined in the node type definitions?

Comment: I think you can use `NodeJS.Process`

Comment: You should not need to use import for typing and change anything in tsconfig with TypeScript >= 2.0.

Comment: Getting "Page not found" for the "You can learn more here." link

Answer (score 4):

It's because inside the node typing file any module has declared with name **node**.

If you use

```
import { Process } from 'node';
```

TypeScript will try too find a **node module** or **node namespace**

Here you can load the complete file using

```
import 'node';
```

In your case you want to get only Process from NodeJS namespace :

```
import 'NodeJS';
```

Aftert that you just need to call it like this :

```
class toto implements NodeJS.Process{

}
```

**EDIT :**

If you use TypeScript >= 2.0 you should not need to add import in your file, only if you want to "optimize import"

Answer (score 2):

In vscode

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd>  > Developer: Reload Window.

Answer (score 1):

I just changed in tsconfig file from

```
"typeRoots": ["./src/interfaces/index.d.ts"]
```

this to

```
"typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"]
```

and its working.

After that I face issue with mongoose library.

```
Module 'mongoose' has no exported member 'QueryFindOneAndUpdateOptions'
```

Then I installed mongoose version library

```
npm install mongoose@5.8.1
```

and it's working now.