# How to give a specified type which is already declared in @types/node?

Tags: typescript

How to replace the `any` type with `NetworkInterfaceInfo[]` type?
I can't import `@types/node` due to this issue: [How to fix "@types/node/index.d.ts is not a module"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44416902/how-to-fix-types-node-index-d-ts-is-not-a-module)

This is my original code:

```
import { networkInterfaces } from 'os';

// array.prototype.concat use type any
const getLocalExternalIP = () => ([] as any).concat(...Object.values(networkInterfaces()))
    .find((info: any) => { // any
        return info.family === 'IPv4' && !info.internal
    }).address

export { getLocalExternalIP };
```

I tried:

```
...
// Cannot find name 'NetworkInterfaceInfo'.ts(2304)
const getLocalExternalIP = () => ([] as NetworkInterfaceInfo[]).concat(  ...
...
```

Can you give me some advice on how to avoid using the any type in this scenario?

Comment: Have you tried typing `concat<NetworkInterfaceInfo[]>` or something like this?

Comment: and why do you need `([] as any)` in the first place?, just destructure it: `[...Object.values(..)]` into a variable, type it and then use `find` on it.

Comment: and last error - `// Cannot find name 'NetworkInterfaceInfo'.ts(2304)`, you need to explicitly import that interface to use it, like `import { networkUnterfaces, NetworkInterfaceInfo } from 'os';` if e.g. `os` module exports it.

Comment: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/node/os.d.ts#L39 it should be importable after installing `@types/node`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can see this - issue with error you are having

```
// Cannot find name 'NetworkInterfaceInfo'.ts(2304)
```

Is because you haven't explicitly imported this module from `os`, like this:

```js
import { networkInterfaces, NetworkInterfaceInfo } from 'os';
```